# How to change the colors of objects in VTK when using vtkAppendPolyData?

Tags: python, colors, vtk

I'm trying to modify the color of each object that I've placed in a `vtkAppendPolyData` but I get weird colors. I mean the object is not in one color but each face of it has a different color.

[image]

I would like to have one color by object.
Here is the minimal example:

```
import vtk
sphereSource = vtk.vtkSphereSource()
sphereSource.SetCenter(5,0,0)
sphereSource.Update()
Colors = vtk.vtkUnsignedCharArray()
Colors.SetNumberOfComponents(3)
Cellarray = sphereSource.GetOutput().GetPolys().GetNumberOfCells()
Colors.SetNumberOfTuples(Cellarray)
for c in range(Cellarray):
    Colors.InsertNextTuple3(255, 0, 0)

sphereSource.GetOutput().GetCellData().SetScalars(Colors)
sphereSource.Update()


coneSource =vtk.vtkConeSource()
coneSource.Update()
Colors = vtk.vtkUnsignedCharArray()
Colors.SetNumberOfComponents(3)
Cellarray = coneSource.GetOutput().GetPolys().GetNumberOfCells()
Colors.SetNumberOfTuples(Cellarray)
for c in range(Cellarray):
    Colors.InsertNextTuple3(0, 255, 0)
coneSource.GetOutput().GetCellData().SetScalars(Colors)
coneSource.Update()

# Append the two meshes
appendFilter = vtk.vtkAppendPolyData()
appendFilter.AddInputData(sphereSource.GetOutput())
appendFilter.AddInputData(coneSource.GetOutput())

appendFilter.Update()

#  Remove any duplicate points.
cleanFilter = vtk.vtkCleanPolyData()
cleanFilter.SetInputConnection(appendFilter.GetOutputPort())
cleanFilter.Update()

# Create a mapper and actor
mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
# mapper.ScalarVisibilityOn()
mapper.SetInputConnection(cleanFilter.GetOutputPort())
mapper.SetColorModeToDirectScalars()

actor = vtk.vtkActor()
actor.SetMapper(mapper)

# Create a renderer, render window, and interactor
renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renderWindow = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
renderWindow.AddRenderer(renderer)
renderWindowInteractor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
renderWindowInteractor.SetRenderWindow(renderWindow)

# Add the actors to the scene
renderer.AddActor(actor)
renderer.SetBackground(.3, .2, .1) #  Background color dark red

# Render and interact
renderWindow.Render()
renderWindowInteractor.Start()
```

Comment: which version of VTK do you use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you set the number of tuples, you should use `InsertTuple3` and not `InsertNextTuple3`, as follow:

```py
Colors.SetNumberOfTuples(Cellarray)
for c in range(Cellarray):
    Colors.InsertTuple3(c, 255, 0, 0)
```

Note that `Insert` is a confusing name here as it does not change the global size and will overwrite the given index. Is more like a `Set` method.

Comment: Okay. I get it.
I thought SetNumberOfTuples allocates the number of tuples I would like to have but I was wrong.
Thanks you so much !

Comment: `SetNumberOfTuples` does the memory allocation but `InsertNext` append value, increasing the array size.