# Weird behavior seting color to vtkPolyData

Tags: python, vtk

I'm trying to assign custom colours to cells in VTK. If I render my model without any colour assignment, it looks like this:

[image]

Now I'm trying to assign diferent colors to every triangle in the mesh. Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59753394/how-to-change-the-colors-of-objects-in-vtk-when-using-vtkappendpolydata) solution I tryied the following to color it in blue (this is a simplification, my colors will depend on the thickness):

```
color = vtk.vtkUnsignedCharArray() 
color.SetName("Colors") 
color.SetNumberOfComponents(3) 
color.SetNumberOfTuples( surface.GetOutput().GetNumberOfCells() )
    
for i in range(surface.GetOutput().GetNumberOfCells()):
    color_tup=[0,0,255]
    color.SetTuple(i, color_tup)
```

I confirm that dimensions of my vtkPolyData and the color array match:

```
assert color.GetNumberOfTuples()==surface.GetOutput().GetNumberOfCells(), "dimensions do not match"
```

Then, I assign the color array to the PolyData as Scalars:

```
surface.GetOutput().GetCellData().SetScalars(color)

mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
mapper.SetInputConnection(surface.GetOutputPort())
mapper.SetColorModeToDirectScalars()

actor = vtk.vtkActor()
actor.SetMapper(mapper)

renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renderWindow = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
renderWindow.AddRenderer(renderer)
renderWindowInteractor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
renderWindowInteractor.SetRenderWindow(renderWindow)

renderer.AddActor(actor)
renderer.SetBackground(1, 1, 1) 

# Render and interact
renderWindow.Render()
renderWindowInteractor.Start()
```

And obtained this (note that I had to change the background to white to distinguish the mesh):

[image]

If I run the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59753394/how-to-change-the-colors-of-objects-in-vtk-when-using-vtkappendpolydata), it works like charm, but If I replace one of the shapes from that solution with my mesh, colours disappear again... Any Idea?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this fix my problem:

```
mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
mapper.SetInputConnection(surface.GetOutputPort())
mapper.SetColorModeToDirectScalars()
mapper.SetScalarModeToUseCellData()
```